# Non Continuous Function Types

Tags: calculus

I have read that there are 3 types of non-continuous function types:

1. $\lim_{ x \to x_0}f(x)\neq f(x_0)$
2. $\lim_{ x \to x_0+}f(x)\neq \lim_{ x \to x_0-}f(x)  $
3. if one of $\lim_{ x \to x_0+}f(x)  $, $\lim_{ x \to x_0-}f(x)$ do not exist

Which type will it be if $f(x_0)$ is not define?

Comment: $f(x)=\dfrac1{x^2}$ is not an $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ function but is an $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\} \to\mathbb{R}$ function.  $f(0)$ being undefined is a problem in the first case but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

note this: a function can only be continuous where it is also defined. To what exactly are you referring when you write "$f(x_0)$ is not defined"?

bests

Comment: When the point we are looking at it's limit is not defined in the function

Comment: as I said, the function needs to defined at $x_0$ to be continuous at $x_0$, see also the example in the comment of Henry above, there the function $f(x)$ can not be continuous simply because $f(0)$ is not defined, but we could of course add this value, let's say we define $x_0=0,f(0):=1$, what happens then?